# What do judges look for at a horse show?

Tags: horses, uk, competitions

I've always wondered what does a judge look for in a horse show?

I know they look at:

- Conformation
- Personality
- Gait
- Presentation

I'll be attending a 2-3 year old all breed class with an Appaloosa.

My issue is the Appaloosa breed notoriously has a small mane/tail which only really grows out with age. In an all breed class I imagine this would be a negative point unless the judge knows about the breed.

I'm based in the UK but other countries will be interesting to read too!

Comment: Do you want an answer generally, or do you want to know how the mane and tail will affect her showing results?

Comment: Hmmm a general one here and I’ll make another linking back to here about her mane and tail specifically :)